# Social counter query

Tags: java, algorithm

I have this challenge to create a facebook-like counter that will show how many people liked a post. I'm relatively new to Java, but have managed to do it. My question is - Is there a more practical and short way of writing the below method?

im just using a simple static array in the Main called users[] with some names in it.

```
public static void facebookCounter(String users[])
{
    if(users.length == 1)
    {
        System.out.println(users[0] + " liked this");
    }

    else if(users.length == 2)
    {
        System.out.println(users[0] + " " + users[1] + " liked this.");
    }
    else if(users.length > 2)
    {
        System.out.println(users[0] + " " + users[1] + " and " + (users.length-2) + " others liked this");
    }


}
```

*Sorry if my pasted code is not formatted well, I pasted it from my intelliJ*

Thanks to anyone who has any ideas!

Comment: How about using the "switch" statement?

Comment: Yes, it is another way, but not necessarily one with less code. Thanks for the suggestion nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be using switch statement rather than if/else:

```
public static void facebookCounter(String users[]) {

    switch (users.length) {
       case 0: break;
       case 1: 
          System.out.println(users[0] + " liked this");
          break;
       case 2:
          System.out.println(users[0] + " " + users[1] + " liked this.");
          break;
       default:
          System.out.println(users[0] + " " + users[1] + " and " + (users.length-2) + " others liked this");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is to stream the first 1 or 2 array items (depending on array's length), collect to String with a joining space char. then, add appropriate suffix:

```
public static void facebookCounter(String users[])
{
    String msg = IntStream.range(0, Math.min(2, users.length))
        .mapToObj(i -> users[i])
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

    if (users.length > 2) msg += " and " + (users.length-2) + " others";
    msg += " liked this";

    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

**EDIT:**
the suffix can be specified in the `joining()` method:

```
    System.out.println(
        IntStream.range(0, Math.min(2, users.length))
            .mapToObj(i -> users[i])
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" ", "",
                users.length > 2 ? " and " + (users.length-2) + " others liked this" : " liked this"
            )
        )
    );
```